# Adding a limit in LEFT JOIN causes incorrect limit amount to return

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, left-join, lateral-join

I am currently working on a query in my Postgres database and getting stuck on a limit i've added to a left join. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    t.id AS "teamId",
    t.name,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(json_agg(Games.games)::TEXT, '[null]'), null)::JSON AS "games"
FROM teams t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            tg.team_id,
            jsonb_build_object(
                'id', tg.id
            ) AS games
        FROM tournament_games tg
        ORDER BY tg.total_points DESC
        LIMIT 4
   )AS Games ON Games.team_id = t.id
WHERE t.tournament_id = 40
GROUP BY t.id
```

The issue I am having is that the `LIMIT 4` is causing only 3 games to return instead of the 4. When I remove the limit, I receive all 6 of the games in my database.

Is there an issue with applying a limit within a left join? Every-time I increase the limit it returns one less than the limit states. (EX. Limit 5 returns 4 games)

EDIT:

When removing the limit, it returns all 6 entries in my database. If a set the limit to 7 (over total entries), it only returns 4 entries.

Does this mean that the query within the LEFT JOIN are returning 7 but the actual JOIN is removing the others?

Comment: What inputs lead to output with those properties? Why would this query return what you expect, given how SQL is defined? If you don't tell us, you're just asking for us to write another book on SQL & expecting us to address your misconceptions without any presentation of your reasoning. Also you know your expectations are wrong, so you ought to compare them with documentation before you considering asking. Also you don't say fully what you want your query to return as a function of input in general, you just give code that doesn't do it. [ask] [help] PS [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want 4 games *per team*. For this, I would recommend a subquery, or lateral join:

```
select t.id as teamid, t.name, tg.games
from teams t
left join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', tg.id)) as games
    from (
        select tg.*
        from tournament_games tg
        where tg.team_id = t.id
        order by tg.total_points desc
        limit 4
    ) tg
) tg on true
where t.tournament_id = 40
```

I am unsure why your want to cast the json object to text - that does not seem really helpful, so I left that apart.

Comment: yes this works! Are there any concerns with scalability using this method?

Comment: @user081608: for performance, consider an index on `tournament_games (team_id, total_points desc)`.